# Simple Arithmetic Puzzle 3. Or is it?

Tags: mathematics

A third one (hopefully it's easier :)!

> $$\begin{align}156+257&=-6\\752+651&=6\\103+482&=-19\\284+301&=31\\654+321&=21\\123+456&=\,?\end{align}$$

Can you find the value of the question mark?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rule:

> $abc+def= b \times c + a - e \times f - d$

**$284 + 301 = 31$**

> $$8\times4 + 2 - 0\times1 - 3 = 31$$
>  Also, it works well for all the given equations.

Value of the question mark:

> **$-27$**
>
>  As $2\times3 + 1 - 5\times6 - 4 = -27$

Comment: How did you find out the pattern?